# When looking at man page, some characters produced by `man` are not rendered

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm

When I do in my terminal a, for instance,

```
man tr
```

I can see that some of the texts are rendered in different colours, based on the control characters which `man` produces in its output, while some are not.

For instance, the terminal displays

```
NAME
 tr <E2><80><93> translate characters
```

from which I conclude, that the hex sequence E28093 is not interpreted. My guess is that this this is a certain unicode character sequence (maybe for a long dash), but I don't understand why it is not shown.

Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot] of my terminal.

My `TERM` variable is set to *xterm-256color* and the `LANG` environment variable is set to *en_GB.utf8* and I don't have neither a `PAGER` nor a `MANPAGER` variable defined, which means that `man` pipes to `less`.

**UPDATE** :
However, I have defined the variable `LESS`, which provides default options for `less`. It's value is `-A --quit-if-one-screen --LONG-PROMPT -X -R`; but I don't see, how this could explain the behaviour. Furthermore, even when I explicitly use a different pager, i.e.

```
MANPAGER=more man tr
```

the output is the same.

Unicode characters seem to be displayed fine. For instance, if I do in the command line (which is zsh) a

```
echo い
```

I see as output an `い`.

This happens with both Terminal.app and iTerm2. The font being used is *Monaco*,

BTW, on request by user `mmmmmm`, I encluse here a screenshot of the output produced by `man -d tr`:

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE**

I did a

```
man tr | tee tmp/man_tr.txt
xxd tmp/mat_tr.txt
```

to see the exact hex code produced by tr. The first couple of lines look like this:

```
00000000: 5452 2831 2920 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  TR(1)           
00000010: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2047 656e               Gen
00000020: 6572 616c 2043 6f6d 6d61 6e64 7320 4d61  eral Commands Ma
00000030: 6e75 616c 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  nual            
00000040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2054 5228 3129             TR(1)
00000050: 0a0a 4e08 4e41 0841 4d08 4d45 0845 0a20  ..N.NA.AM.ME.E. 
00000060: 2020 2020 7408 7472 0872 20e2 8093 2074      t.tr.r ... t
00000070: 7261 6e73 6c61 7465 2063 6861 7261 6374  ranslate charact
00000080: 6572 730a 0a53 0853 5908 594e 084e 4f08  ers..S.SY.YN.NO.
00000090: 4f50 0850 5308 5349 0849 5308 530a 2020  OP.PS.SI.IS.S.  
000000a0: 2020 2074 0874 7208 7220 5b2d 082d 4308     t.tr.r [-.-C.
000000b0: 4363 0863 7308 7375 0875 5d20 5f08 735f  Cc.cs.su.u] _.s_
```

We can see the ominous byte sequence e28093 occuring in the line at offset 60. What on earth is this? It can't be a UTF-8 sequence (there are no 3-byte-sequences starting with E2).

Furthermore these ghost codes don't appear on **every** man page. I see it with i.e. `man cat`, but they don't show with `man man`, `man zsh` or `man bash`..... But there is a system in it:

I have installed via Homebrew the [Gnu tools](https://gist.github.com/skyzyx/3438280b18e4f7c490db8a2a2ca0b9da) for the Mac. For installing them, there are two options: (1) Have them replace the original files, i.e. GNU-tr replaces the MacOS-tr, or (2) leave the original binaries unchanged and install the GNU tools under a new name, i.e. the GNU-tr is now named `/usr/local/bin/gtr`, while the original tr is still available as `/usr/bin/tr`. I have decided to go for the second option, i.e. have the GNU-versions along with the BSD-versions, but in different directories. Since their name differs, there should be no problem with `PATH` either. BTW, I have not defined the variable `MANPATH` either, but again this should not matter since the programs are named differently (`tr` vs. `gtr`).

Now when I do a

```
man gtr
```

I see the GNU tr manpage, formatted nicely; but when I just do a

```
man tr
```

I see the BSD tr manpage, with the E2-hex-sequence in it. At least this shows, under what condition it happens - the whole mess is related to the GNU utilities -, although I still don't understand, WHY it happens.

Comment: Do you have an environment variable MANPAGER and if so what is its value?

Comment: What does `man -d tr` show as the command?

Comment: @mmmmmm : No MANPAGER, but a variable `LESS`; see my update to my question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read that last image could you please paste the relevant line - the last one as text [ and also what does `which man` show? and the version of macOS

Comment: The last one says: _ man:  not executing command:  /usr/bin/mandoc -W unsupp,stop /usr/share/man/man1/tr.1 2>&1 >/dev/null_

Comment: @mmmmmm : `type -a man` shows: _/usr/bin/man_ ... It's just the "normal" man command from MacOS.

Comment: @mmmmmm : This is on a Macbook running Monterey. I also have an iMac running Catalina. On that one, the `man tr` works fine.

Comment: @mmmmmmm : Please could you have a look again at my last update? I think I have found the root cause, though I don't understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: I don't get your comment re GNU and what you have shown. The man command is the BSD one in both cases. Also it seems to be macOS version specific. I suspect that /usr/share/man/man1/tr.1 is corrupt - could you compare that file between your machines. ALso not that the actual commands man -d show also differ in my ventura

Comment: @mmmmmmm : This would be logical. I also suspected that the error is in the man-page. However, looking at tr.1, I don't see an erroneous hex E2 character in it, and I wonder what produces this. The only observation connection to the GNU-utilities seems to be, that the problem occurs only with man-pages of those BSD-tools, where also a GNU-equivalent has been installed.

Comment: @mmmmmm : I think jksoegaard is on the right track: The hex sequence in question is an en-dash, and while I don't know, why it is placed there (perhaps an effect on how troff is configured), it seems that the pagers `less` and `more` have problems with it, even though the terminal itself can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found (with the valuable help of the comments by *mmmmmm* and *jksoergaard*) that my pagers (`less` and `more`) have problems displaying UTF8 multibyte characters, and that this is unrelated to `man`. Therefore I think we can regard **this** question as closed. However, I will research the issue of multibyte characters and pagers (maybe they simply don't work together), and post a new question on this topic, if necessary.

At least for `less`, an explanation seems to be [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/414760/how-to-make-the-less-command-handle-utf-8). It does not mention `more`, but I can man the man-page work with less, if I set

```
export LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

**UPDATE** : As pointed out by user *mmmmmm*, /usr/bin/more and /usr/bin/less point to the same inode, which explains why `more` also behaves in this way.

Comment: In macOS the Apple more and less are the same (they are hard linked together)

Comment: @mmmmmm : Indeed, they have the same inode number! I will put this into my answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The "mysterious hex sequence" is actually just the UTF-8 bytes for an en dash - in hex that is 0xE28093.

The en dash is supposed to be there - it's in the man page. The output of those bytes (0xE28093) from `man` is also as it is supposed to be on a standard installation.

The problem on your installation could be with the terminal software or its configuration. When using `Terminal.app`, check its `Settings` and make sure that under the `Profiles` tab in the `Advanced` sub-tab, below the `International` header, it should say `"Text encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)"`.

According to your comments, you have already that the same bytes just output using `cat` results in the correct dash character.

Therefore the problem is most probably with your pageer settings.  You could try removing `-X` and `-R` from the `LESS` environment variable. Just set the variable to empty and try the man command to see if there's an effect.

Comment: May I ask how you identified this sequence as en-dash? Initially, I also suspected that this is some kind of dash, but when I enter this sequence in [this](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html?q=) search engine, it did not find anything unusual.

Comment: Of course, the terminal settings (for instance the font set) is a potential suspect. However, after saving the man page to a text file and verifying that it still contains E28093, I can do a `cat` of this text file and the output looks fine. Now that you found out that it describes an en-dash, I can indeed see, when looking closely, that the dash at this position looks slightly different (`tr – translate characters`). This proves at least that the terminal does not have a problem printing this character. This means that the pager is the culprit.

Comment: I also tried to unset the variable `LESS`, but no effect. Plus, it also doesn't explain, why using the pager `more` does not show the problem.

Comment: You're using a Unicode search engine. In UTF-8, some characters are encoded using multi-byte sequences. The 0xE2 is the start of such a multi-byte sequence.

Comment: Check for example this page to see that it is correct that this is an UTF-8 encoding of en-dash: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: Yes, the pager seems to be the problem here. Your LESS settings are weird.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to fileformat.info. I thought that when I checked the checkbox "UTF-8 bytes" on that search engine, it would allow me to enter the whole sequence. This was obviously too naive.

Comment: The settings might be odd, but it does not explain, why we have the same effect with different settings or a different pager.......